# OrderBy возвращает using filesort

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE work
(
    id          INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    workName    VARCHAR(255)           NOT NULL,
    userId      INT                    NOT NULL,
    likes       INT DEFAULT '0'        NOT NULL,
    description TEXT                   NULL,
    approved    TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    created_at  TIMESTAMP              NULL,
    updated_at  TIMESTAMP              NULL
);
CREATE INDEX work_approved_index
    ON work (approved);
CREATE INDEX work_likes_index
    ON work (likes);
CREATE INDEX work_userid_index
    ON work (userId);
```

Заглянул в explain, вижу Using where; Using filesort, не понимаю куда и как оптимизировать

```
EXPLAIN SELECT likes, approved
    FROM `work`
    WHERE `work`.`approved` = TRUE
    ORDER BY `work`.`likes`, approved
```

Талица планируется быть достаточно большой, поэтому хотелось бы избежать сортировки

Comment: Освойте составные индексы.

Comment: Даже если тут использовать составной индекс, результат будет тот же.

Comment: Да ладно! результат тот же... `CREATE INDEX idx_approved_likes ON work (approved,likes);`. И сразу `DROP INDEX work_approved_index;` - за ненадобностью. Если и после этого останется filesort - значит, таблица слишком мала, чтобы дёргать её за индексы. Впрочем индекс всё равно будет использоваться - ибо покрывающий.

Comment: Действительно я не прав. Я делал составной индекс в неверной последовательности, поэтому получал filesort. Вы мне помогли

Comment: Ну... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @StereoFlo, теперь, когда Вы знаете ответ - пишете его как ответ и помечаете верным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос простой: необходим составной индекс в правильной последовательности, в этом и заключалась моя ошибка:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_approved_likes ON work (approved,likes);
```